# How to use onChange in custom textinput react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So im new at react native and i built an custom text input that gives suggestions by following a tutorial.But now i cant use onChange  in that custom text input.I tried to  create a state in App.js  and change it in AutoCompleteText.js file but didnt worked.How can i get the value inmy custom text input ?

my App.js file :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AutoCompleteText from './AutoCompleText'
import './AutoCompleteText.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.AutoComp}>
      <AutoCompleteText items={['Ali','Veli','Ahmet']} />
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },
  AutoComp:{
    width:600

  }
});
```

my AutoCompleteText.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import './AutoCompleteText.css';

export default class AutoCompleteText extends React.Component{



    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            suggestions:[],
            text:'',
            
        };

    }


    onTextChanged = (e) =>{
        const {items} = this.props;
        const value = e.target.value;
        let suggestions = [];
        if (value.length > 0){
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`,'i');
            suggestions = items.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
            
            
    }
    this.setState(() => ({ suggestions , text: value }));

}



    suggestionSelected(value){
        this.setState(() =>({
            text: value,
            suggestions:[],
        }) )

    }


    renderSuggestions(){

    const {suggestions} = this.state;
    if (suggestions.length === 0){

        return null;
    }
    return(
        <ul>
            {suggestions.map((item) => <li onClick={() => this.suggestionSelected(item)}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    );
}




    render(){
        const { text } = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="AutoCompleteText">
                <input value={text} onChange={this.onTextChanged} type ='text'/>
                {this.renderSuggestions()}
             
            </div>


        )


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi Ülkü Tuncer Küçüktaş,
You are writing the wrong syntax. You are mixing the syntax of react native with react. In react native for textinput, you should use the [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) Component(Built in component from docs).

The syntax of react native TextInput look like below

```
    import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}

export default UselessTextInput;
```